# mysql load data infile can't get the stat of file

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load a csv file into mySQL with the following command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/alcoa_2012_05_15.csv' into table alcoa fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
(@var1, Time, volume, open, close, min, max)
set date = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%d-%b-%y')
```

and I get the following error

```
error 13, load data infile can't get stat of file Errcode: 2
```

which says it cannot find the data file. I have tried small variations on the command :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ...
```

all else the same and now I get the following error msg:

```
ERROR 1148, The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version!
```

I am using the latest download of MySQL on Ubuntu 12.04 ( both installed 2 weeks ago)

I am baffled, after lots of searching this forum had previous questions answered which were close, but not quite an answer.

Thanks

Jefe

Comment: Did you check this file's privileges?

Comment: "LOAD DATA" is for a file on the database server.  "LOAD DATA LOCAL" is for a file on the client.  Which do you have?

Comment: As @raina77ow alluded to, make sure the acount the mysql daemon is using can see the file.

Comment: The server is on the same machine, and I saved the file myself, so privilege shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: the csv file priviveges are -rw-rw-r--

Comment: @raina77ow, the file privileges are, rw-rw-r-- ; interestingly the /var/lib/mysql directory, is one i dont have read access to, would that cause a problem?   The MySQL manual comments on a bug introduced in MySQL 5.17 which comments that the LOAD DATA command can be affected by the secure-file-priv which limits the path that LOAD DATA can see:    http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv

Answer (score 5):

Try to replace your "LOAD DATA" with "LOAD DATA **LOCAL**"

- "LOAD DATA" is for a file on the database server.
- "LOAD DATA LOCAL" is for a file on the client. Which do you have?

Answer (score 1):

This problem was really frustrating, until I found that MySQL had its own private tmp `systemd-private-abcdef` folder in `/tmp`. So it could never find the file and do the load data.

The solution was to set:
`PrivateTmp=false` in the `/etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service` file.
 
In my case the file ended up looking like this:

```
.include /usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=20000
PrivateTmp=false
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was unable to load data to MySQL table, then I resolved the issue myself.

Error code 13 is nothing but the permission issues.

Error code 02 is when it is unable to find the file.

***Here's the solution:***

Check the path of your file, if it is correct then it's the permission issue which can be solved as follows:
By default the `local-infile` is set to value 0. In order to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` **it must be enabled.**

So *Start MySQL* like this:

> mysql -u username -p --local-infile

This will make `LOCAL INFILE` enabled during start-up and thus there won't be any issue using it!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @raina77ow, for the [suggestion to check the file's permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485942/mysql-load-data-infile-cant-get-the-stat-of-file#comment16799240_12485942).
I spent a long time looking at everything else. I finally saw your post and took a look.

My problem wasn't the permissions though, it was an extra extension I placed on the file because the folder was set to hide known extensions.

Looking at the file's properties in windows explorer allowed me to see and correct the extra `.txt` at the end.

Once I fixed it, load data local infile worked like a charm as it had with other files.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I think another significant problem here has not yet been addressed for users. 
It's a simple question of not being able to locate a file either using the `mysql> shell` or even `mysqlimport` command from the command line (Errorcode 2).

A quite natural unix/linux user assumption is that the user is:

1. running import operations from a given directory
2. running `mysqlimport` or the `shell`
3. locating the file he wants to import there
4. then assuming that no additional pathing would be needed, i.e. just the
   filename or the relative path to it.

But it has became apparent to me that the relative path used by MySQL is in the location of the database directory for MySQL, i.e. `/usr/lib/mysql/<dbname>`.
**It is looking there for the file that is named without any pathing**, thus the Errorcode 2!

That is the home of the database into which a user wants to import, so it looks there, and not the directories from which you are launching the shell and especially the command line import command, `mysqlimport`.

This is very counter-intuitive for the `mysqlimport` command to the point where I'd call it a defect. I am not sure if the MySQL db directory is a controllable location at installation of MySQL, so it may be different for any particular system. 
**The solution is to always give the absolute path to the file being imported.**  BINGO!  I tested this out by granting permissions to write a file there, (dir is owned by the "MySQL" user), accessing it with a relative path then, and absolute paths on the shell and command line commands. I redid the db after goofing with the MySQL permissions to be sure!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Debian another solution would be to move the file into your "/tmp" directory. That solved the problem for me.